# Flexslider Carousel: Selectbox inside breaks it all on iPad 1 and iPhone 4

Tags: jquery, ios, flexslider, select-menu

I got the following problem:
When a selectbox is placed inside a flexslider carousel and I open the **select-dialog on iPad 1 (iOS 4.3.3) or iPhone 4 (iOs 4.3.5), all content from the slider is displaced to the left...** on the first select menu, when I haven't moved the slider, there's no problem. In all other cases, this strange problem occurs. :/

See it here, it's the flexslider carousel original demo, only with select menus placed inside:
**http://allcontrasts.com/flexslider-problem/demo/**

Does anyone have an idea why this happens? Or even how this can be solved?

Thanks in advance!
 Jonas